# Is there any way to center a map (Google Map) based where's located a layer from carto

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, cartodb

I'm getting a layer from carto using carto.js v4 and showing it on a map (Google Map) and I wanna center the map where is the layer located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get that info using [SQL API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/) and PostGIS functions, in general the easy approach is to center the map in the bounding box of your data so that would be sending this query

```
select st_asgeojson(
           st_boundingdiagonal(
               st_collect(
                   the_geom)))
  from populated_places
```

That query will give you the coordinates of the [corners of the bounding box](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_BoundingDiagonal.html) as a GeoJSON object, very easy to parse and translate into a Google Maps API map change.